# How do I deduct time in excel cells with out causing #### error?

Tags: excel

I am trying to deduct time in excel.

There are 2 cells and I'm trying to do = with cell1 coordinates - cell2 coordinates.

This is working fine in most of the sheet with the cells formatted as custom hh:mm

In these particular cells I'm getting ###########  rather than the answer

Upon looking further in to why this is happening one of the cells in the calculation is simply showing the time whilst one is showing `07/01/1900  00:57:30` in the top bar. The cell is also formatted to HH:MM so why does it show a date in the bar at the top rather than just the time??

I believe I'm getting the ##### error because on the cell it looks like the above and the other just shows the time as

```
04:42
```

How do I stop the first cell from looking like a date plus time in the formula bar?

Comment: Usually ## will be displayed in the cells of lesser width. You may resize the column and check still it shows ##.

Comment: try changing the format to `[h]:mm` to avoid any time greater than 24 hours not showing all the time

Answer (score 0):

If the cell with 07/01/1900 00:53:30 is supposed to be a time then you should consider it as indicating 7 days offset in time (assuming that format is dd/mm/yyyy).  I get the same results if the cell number is 7.039930556, and I format it for HH:MM.

However that number was generated, it has an offset of 7 days (suspiciously one week!).  I suggest looking at how it was generated, it might be due to a wrap around issue.

If you really just want the time value and don't care why there is an integer offset, you can use the function MOD `MOD( A1, 1)` will return only the fractional amount of the number, which represents the fractional amount in a day, which is the time.

Excel time and date is representing in days since Jan 1st, 1900.  0.5 is 12 hours.  0.1 is 2.4 hours.

Comment: whats an integer offset

Comment: An integer is a whole number.  An offset is an addition.  0.039930556 has 7 added to it.  7 is the integer offset.